# How do I use the trait scala.Proxy

Tags: scala, dynamic, proxy, scala-2.8

I just found it [in the API](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Proxy.html) and would like to see one or two examples along with an explanation what it is good for.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Proxy trait provides a useful basis for creating delegates, but note that it only provides implementations of the methods in `Any` (`equals`, `hashCode`, and `toString`). You will have to implement any additional forwarding methods yourself. Proxy is often used with the [pimp-my-library pattern](https://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=179766):

```
class RichFoo(val self: Foo) extends Proxy {
   def newMethod = "do something cool"
}

object RichFoo {
   def apply(foo: Foo) = new RichFoo(foo)
   implicit def foo2richFoo(foo: Foo): RichFoo = RichFoo(foo)
   implicit def richFoo2foo(richFoo: RichFoo): Foo = richFoo.self
}
```

The standard library also contains a set of traits that are useful for creating collection proxies (`SeqProxy`, `SetProxy`, `MapProxy`, etc).

Finally, there is a compiler plugin in the scala-incubator (the [AutoProxy plugin](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=275135)) that will automatically implement forwarding methods. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473309/proxies-delegates-in-scala).

Comment: The currently active version of that plugin is autoproxy-lite: https://github.com/kevinwright/Autoproxy-Lite

Comment: Any ideas on how to best solve this today with scala 2.11, 2.12, and 2.13?

Comment: The `pimp-my-library` link is broken now.

Comment: @GrzegorzOledzki I updated the link, redirecting it to a 2006 blog post on the topic by Martin Odersky.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you'd use it when you need Haskell's `newtype` like functionality.

For example, the following Haskell code:

```
newtype Natural = MakeNatural Integer
                  deriving (Eq, Show)
```

may roughly correspond to following Scala code:

```
case class Natural(value: Int) extends Proxy {
  def self = value
}
```

Comment: So this is basically machinery for creating delegates?