# Use cases of Scala collection forwarders and proxies

Tags: scala, scala-2.8, scala-collections

Scala's collection library contains the forwarders [`IterableForwarder`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/generic/IterableForwarder.html), [`TraversableForwarder`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/generic/TraversableForwarder.html), [`SeqForwarder`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/generic/SeqForwarder.html) and proxies like [`IterableProxy`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/IterableProxy.html), [`MapProxy`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/MapProxy.html), [`SeqProxy`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/SeqProxy.html), [`SetProxy`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/SetProxy.html), [`TraversableProxy`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/TraversableProxy.html), etc. Forwarders and proxies both delegate collection methods to an underlying collection object. The main difference between these two are that forwarders don't forward calls that would create new collection objects of the same kind.

In which cases would I prefer one of these types over the other? Why and when are forwarders useful? And if they are useful why are there no `MapForwarder` and `SetForwarder`?

I assume proxies are most often used if one wants to build a wrapper for a collection with additional methods or to pimp the standard collections.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900827/how-do-i-use-the-trait-scala-proxy/3901166#3901166) provides some context about `Proxy` in general (and your assumption about wrapper and pimping would be correct).

As far as I can tell the subtypes of `Proxy` are more targeted to end users. When using `Proxy` the proxy object and the `self` object will be *equal* for all intent and purposes. I think that's actually the main difference. Don't use `Proxy` if that assumption does not hold.

The *Forwarder* traits only seems to be used to support `ListBuffer` and may be more appropriate if one needs to roll out their own collection class built on top of the `CanBuildFrom` infrastructure. So I would say it's more targeted to library writers where the library is based on the 2.8 collection design.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! That the _Forwarder_ traits are only used for `ListBuffer` may answer the question why there are no `MapForwarder` and `SetForwarder`: because they are not required for implementing `ListBuffer`.