# What benefits does Proxy[T] have over an implicit class?

Tags: scala, implicit

In the Scala standard library there is a class `Proxy[T]`. From the API:

> This class implements a simple proxy that forwards all calls to the public, non-final methods defined in class Any to another object self.

From the above, and numerous Q&A in stack overflow regarding this class, I would infer that this is the same as using an `implicit class`.

Is this correct? **If so, what are the advantages/disadvantages of using the `Proxy` class over the `implicit` keyword?**

Answer (score 2):

These two things are entirely unrelated. The description of `Proxy` is a bit misleading. All it does is implemented `hashCode`, `equals` and `toString` in terms of the peer object. It doesn't have magic power to forward any other methods.

See also this question: [How do I use the trait scala.Proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900827/how-do-i-use-the-trait-scala-proxy)

Comment: Referring to the related question, the accepted answer suggests using `Proxy` to extend another class with new methods. You could achieve the same with code `implicit class RichFoo(self: Foo) {
   def newMethod = "do something cool"
}`. Isn't this the same thing in practice?

Comment: Frankly, I don't know why you would ever want to use `Proxy`. Certainly I have never done it…